# Port Forwading With two Different IP Addresses (Public IP and WAN IP)

Tags: ssh, android

Actually i stablished a ssh server on the android and i want to connect to it from outside the LAN so I need the IP of my modem which have a two different IP Address; The Public IP address 110.52.x.x that shows up when i ask google what is my ip and the WAN IP that the modem shows me in the config gateway. How can i solve this problem? I have tried searching for this kind of problem but i don't see any solution for it.

I use SSHDroid App to establish a SSH server and currently listening to 192.168.254.111:2222

Comment: Search here for `CGN`. You cannot port forward on your ISPs NAPT router, so trying to provide services to the public Internet from you LAN is prohibited by your ISP Terms of Service, so they do not care that CGN breaks your attempt to do that.

Comment: Your ISP is likely using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: How about bypassing the CGN? Is there a thing like that?

Answer (score -1):

Actually i found a way. I tried to bypass CGN using ngrok.

First things first! i downloaded the [Linux (ARM)](https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-arm.zip) file
and then because my android is already rooted i moved it to `/system/bin` using an app called root browser where i can access it directly in the terminal so i won't need to type `./ngrok` anyway after that, i downloaded SSHDroid (NO IM NOT SPONSORING SOME APP) then start the SSH server...In the Meanwhile while SSHDroid is listening. In the terminal i type `ngrok tcp -region ap 192.168.xxx.xxx:22`. the 22 here is the port where SSHDroid is Listening.

You can also check my SSH server here --> 0.tcp.ap.ngrok.io
port:14315

Check it here [SSH CHECKER](https://sshcheck.com/)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so together with detailed instructions.